# ftp command to download file by date

Tags: batch-file, ftp, sftp

I am using .bat script to access sftp and download file. The ftp folder consist of a lot of file which can be uniquely identify by the file name in format YYYYMMDD. eg: 20180307.csv, 20180306.csv etc. Currently I am using mget to get all the file, then at later filter it locally. How can I modify the script to get the file on today only?

This is my .bat script.

```
    D:
    CD\myTargetFolder
    psftp user@sftp.myftpserver.com -pw password -b mySftpScript.ftp
    exit
```

This is my ftp script.

```
    cd /myFTPSourceFolder
    mget *.csv
    bye
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind dynamically creating the ftp script then perhaps your .bat script could look like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D D:\myTargetFolder 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "csv="
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy /NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined csv Set "csv=%%A%%B%%C.csv"
(   Echo cd /myFTPSourceFolder
    Echo mget %csv%
    Echo bye)>"mySftpScript.ftp"
psftp user@sftp.myftpserver.com -pw password -b mySftpScript.ftp
::Del "mySftpScript.ftp"
```

*I've commented out the last line, remove the `::` from it if you wish to delete the dynamically created ftp script.*

**Edit**

To get yesterday's date csv then something like this, *leveraging PowerShell*, would be my recommendation:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D D:\myTargetFolder 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "csv="
For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyMMdd')"`
) Do Set "csv=%%A.csv"
(   Echo cd /myFTPSourceFolder
    Echo mget %csv%
    Echo bye)>"mySftpScript.ftp"
psftp user@sftp.myftpserver.com -pw password -b mySftpScript.ftp
::Del "mySftpScript.ftp"
```

Comment: Hi. How can I modify it to get yesterday date csv?

Comment: I've added an Edit to my answer to cater for your new request. _Please note however, that this new request was technically a new question and as such should have been posted as one._